# How to Add Handler Id to Options value loaded by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a select options by using jQuery from 3 arrays to one select list on click which so far works fine for me at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/52VtD/1419/)
But I have an issue here.if you look at the values I have same value on three list so I have to upgrade them by adding also the id of the clicked button to the value some thing like this:

```
<option value="regi1NNN">NNN</option>
```

instead of

```
<option value="NNN">NNN</option>
```

depends on what button clicked.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var opt1 = ["AAAA", "BBBB", "NNN", "JJJJJ"];
    var opt2 = ["KKKK", "FFFF", "NNN", "TTTTT"];
    var opt3 = ["MMM", "NNN", "OOOO", "PPPPP"];

    $("#regi1").click(function () {
        $('#items option').remove();
        var option = '';
        for (i = 0; i < opt1.length; i++) {
            option += '<option value="' + opt1[i] + '">' + opt1[i] + '</option>';
        }
        $('#items').append(option);
    });
    $("#regi2").click(function () {
        $('#items option').remove();
        var option = '';
        for (i = 0; i < opt2.length; i++) {
            option += '<option value="' + opt2[i] + '">' + opt2[i] + '</option>';
        }
        $('#items').append(option);
    });
    $("#regi3").click(function () {
        $('#items option').remove();
        var option = '';
        for (i = 0; i < opt3.length; i++) {
            option += '<option value="' + opt3[i] + '">' + opt3[i] + '</option>';
        }
        $('#items').append(option);
    });

});
```

Comment: Do you not think it would be better to include a separate hidden input in the form that tells you which button was clicked rather than mess up the value?

Comment: Or since you're outputting each element in separate loops anyway, just add the string `value="' + this.id + opt1[i] + '"`. By the way, you can do all in just one click function instead of three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your options like so:

```
option += '<option value="' +  opt1[i] + '">' + opt1[i] + '</option>';
```

Simply add the id of the clicked element as a prefix:

```
option += '<option value="' + this.id + opt1[i] + '">' + opt1[i] + '</option>';
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/g8euy/  This way when you combine all your click handlers into one function (which you should, since you have three functions that do the same thing) you'll be all set.

**UPDATE:** I rewrote your code to only use a single funciton. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/n2tBC/1/

I added a class and a data attribute to your buttons:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="well">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default listy" id="regi1" data-vals="opt1">Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default listy" id="regi2" data-vals="opt2">Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default listy" id="regi3" data-vals="opt3">Right</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <select id="items"></select>
</div>
</div>
```

And then the script combines your value lists into an object, and there's a single function that gets the data based on the data-val of the clicked button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var myVals = {
    opt1:  ["AAAA", "BBBB", "NNN", "JJJJJ"],
    opt2:  ["KKKK", "FFFF", "NNN", "TTTTT"],
    opt3: ["MMM", "NNN", "OOOO", "PPPPP"]
}


$(".listy").click(function () {
    $('#items option').remove();
    var clickedButton = $(this);
    var valueList = myVals[clickedButton.data('vals')];
    var option = '';
    for (i = 0; i < valueList.length; i++) {
        option += '<option value="' + this.id + valueList[i] + '">' + valueList[i] + '</option>';
    }
    $('#items').append(option);
});

});
```

Now when you add more buttons, you don't add more code.

Comment: Thanks a lot veddermatic, it was really helpful